# How to add a route in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm a newbie in javascript and vue.js and I'm facing some issue when trying to add a new route in an existing programme.

I created my new component in a separate file called Miniature.vue

I added the new route in the router definition:

```
  export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/certificat/:id',
      name: 'Certificat',
      component: Certificat
    },
    {
      path: '/miniature/:id',
      name: 'Miniature',
      component: Miniature
    }
  ]
})
```

And then, in the vue instantiation, I added my new components and updated the template :

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
components: { Certificat, Miniature } ,
template: '<div>
            <Certificat></Certificat>
            <Miniature></Miniature>
            </div>'
})
```

The previous template was simply

```
template: '<Certificat/>'
```

Problem is, the url is either mywebsite/certificat/123 or  mywebsite/miniature/123, both routes are executed, and my two components are displayed !
What is the purpose of the template in the Vue constructor anyway? If I remove it, nothing happens.

What am I missing here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those components are supposed to be loaded from your route, so they shouldn't be in your app template (i.e., they should be removed from `#app`'s `components` and `template`).

Your app should contain [`<router-view>`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view) somewhere for the route to be rendered. In your case, replace the app template string with `<router-view/>`.

It should look similar to this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<router-view/>'
})
```

I should mention your router setup is missing a route for `/` and `404`, so the default path and unknown routes will render nothing in your app. Users would have to navigate to the exact routes you've configured to see anything.

Comment: This works better. Thanks for the clarification. How can I add a route for 404 ?

Comment: No problem :) For 404, use a `path: '*'` as the last route. Example: `{ path: '*', component: { template: '<div>Not found {{$route.path}}</div>' } }`

Comment: Thanks @tony19 Is there a way to make different routes for different error codes ? (one for 404, one for 500...)

Answer (score 0):

Vue doesn't have routing built-in, for routing you'll need the [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) package.

To get a better understanding of `template` and Vue in general, I recommend reading  the [Introduction guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html)

Comment: Already read it, didn't find any answer to my problem... thanks anyway...